# Developing an RSS Feed Reader in C++

Tags: c++, xml, sockets

I wanna write a simple RSS Feed reader in C++.
I understand that the basic requirement is to understand XML parsing ( at the low level), opening, reading/writing, closing sockets and stuff like that. I don't need help in coding for sure. But It would be great if someone can help in getting started with RSS Protocol. E.g.. How exactly do I open socket ( for http I used 80, for IRC I had used the 6667 and so on).. and the protocol or commands to interact with a RSS Feed socket. I've also contemplated using third party libraries for XML n stuff. But I wanna do everything from scratch.
Any help would be appreciated! and also, if not in the right direction.. please guide !

Thanks and Regards,
Vamsi Krishna

Comment: If someone else ends up here and is looking for a library, today I would recommend pugixml for parsing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to "do everything from scratch" as a learning exercise then go for it.  However, if your goal is a to write an app to solve a problem then I'd suggest using off-the-shelf librarys as much as possible.

Assuming you're after the learning experience...

- Make a socket connection to port 80 on the server hosting the RSS feed
- Send an **[HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)** request for the feed
- Receive the feed
- Parse the **[feed](http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html)**

And I guess you want to write your own **[XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/)** parser?

Answer (score 3):

To get started, just go to [http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/c++], which is an RSS feed for StackOverflow C++ question. As you can see it's an ordinary HTTP connection. View source.